# MySQL - For Statement check for value in another table

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I'm trying to use a for statement in PHP to check if each row in a table contains one of multiple values stored in another table.

```
$permCount = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$dealId`")->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)[0];
$location = "SELECT * FROM `$dealId` WHERE ID = $count AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ireland_counties WHERE county = '*')";


for($count = 1; $count <= $permCount; $count++) {
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $location)) {
        echo 'UK' . $count . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else {
        echo 'IRELAND' . $count . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what I have wrong here. I have 325 rows which do not contain one of the Counties, and one which does. If I delete the row which does, then the loop displays all 325 UK rows. But if the single IRELAND row exists then it will only run the loop once, and still display UK.

Comment: You have to set `$location` variable inside the `for` loop (or use prepared statements). Currently, you are setting the statement once with an (unitialized) `$count`-value, and `$location` will stay the same. On the other hand, your code will probably not work at all. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but `(SELECT 1 FROM ireland_counties WHERE county = '*')` will be the same for every query. And on the third hand, you could get your result for all rows at once. You don't have to execute that query for every row, just leave away the `WHERE ID = $count` and fetch all result rows.

Comment: @Solarflare Okay, I thought that the $count value would be set, as the $location variable is being called inside the loop. I hadn't realised that I could ignore the ID = $count and just use a single statement. I had it in my head that I had to loop through each row. I'll look into doing it that way.